# MSAL + Angular : How to silently log in users quickly

Tags: angular, azure-ad-msal, msal.js

I'm using MSAL JS (Azure AD B2C) + Angular (v5). Everything is working fine, except that the silent login is very slow. This causes an iframe to be loaded; which will re-bootstrap the entire site again after retrieving the token from Azure. So, this is quite heavy in terms of performance.

So, my plan is to do the silent login from `main.ts` and in this case not do the bootstrapping. I already feel that this will cause issues, and it feels hacky. Is this the best solution? Open to suggestions.

Comment: Could you post some snippet of how you're setting things up?

Comment: I have come across the same issue and finally switched to Auth0 which has better performance

Comment: @HarryNinh I'm just executing following code in my main app constructor: 

this.userAgentApp.acquireTokenSilent(authSettings.scopes, null, this.userAgentApp.getUser()).then((accessToken) => {
 ....
      }, (error) => {

Answer (score 0):

Since you are open to suggestions, I'll suggest some. 
There are two methods for MSAL login.

1. Loginredirect , Acquiretokensilent, GetcachedToken - Can use for websites only . Remember to set handleRedirectCallback for login.

```js
msalInstance.handleRedirectCallback((error, response) => {
        // handle redirect response or error
    });
```

2. Loginpopup - Can use for iframes and websites. It also returns a promise, so callback can be performed there.

```js
   msalInstance.loginPopup(loginRequest)
        .then(response => {
            // handle response
        })
        .catch(err => {
            // handle error
        });
```

You cant use displaycall feature in MSAL which helps silent login in ADAL.

Upvote if it helped!